# al redimensionar el formulario se me oculta el titulo del eje X

Tags: c#, windows-forms

[image: al redimensionar como se observa se superpone el chart area al titulo del eje]

al redimensionar como se observa se superpone el chartArea al titulo del eje, tengo un chart control con dos chartAreas, una encima de otra, al hacer mas pequeño el tab que las contienen los títulos de los ejes X se superponen e incluso llegan a desaparecer, sin embargo las chartAreas si se redimensionan correctamente

Comment: tienes que jugar con las propiedades anchor y dock de los elementos. Anchor te indica hacia donde "crece" el control en cuestion, y Dock dice que espacio tiene a ocupar

Comment: en este caso no es aplicable, las áreas esta contenidas dentro en un control chart, carecen de esa propiedad, algo se me escapa con respecto al marco que las rodea.